# Error while installing Sinch JS RTC as npm package

Tags: node.js, sinch

I need to use Sinch IM feature from my backend server and I am trying to install sinch-rtc as node.js package. I get the following error when I use the command : npm install sinch-rtc --save

Here is the [Debug Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/daj5nd4nv3j5t66/npm-debug.log?dl=0),

Please correct me if I am missing something. Thanks.

```
npm WARN engine agentkeepalive@0.2.4: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
|
> wrtc@0.0.55 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading 32-bit node.lib
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:369:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:998:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\sinch-rtc\\node_modules\\wrtc\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\sinch-rtc\\node_modules\\wrtc\\build\\wrtc\\v0.0.55\\Release\\node-v46-win32-x64\\wrtc.node" "--module_name=wrtc" "--module_path=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\sinch-rtc\\node_modules\\wrtc\\build\\wrtc\\v0.0.55\\Release\\node-v46-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\build\wrtc\v0.0.55\Release\node-v46-win32-x64\wrtc.node --module_name=wrtc --module_path=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\build\wrtc\v0.0.55\Release\node-v46-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:73:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\sinch-rtc\\node_modules\\wrtc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\build\wrtc\v0.0.55\Release\node-v46-win32-x64\wrtc.node --module_name=wrtc --module_path=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sinch-rtc\node_modules\wrtc\build\wrtc\v0.0.55\Release\node-v46-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sinch-rtc" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! wrtc@0.0.55 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the wrtc@0.0.55 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the wrtc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls wrtc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? if so can you mark my answer as complete- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facinc is node-gyp doesnt work on your system. 
Follow the instructions on node-gyp https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp and try to install node-gyp only to start with.